# frequent warning in resource adaptor JBAS011843

Tags: java, jboss

I am getting frequent warnings like below.
Jboss EAP 6.x.x we are using.

```
2016-09-06 13:20:35,584 WARNING [com.sun.genericjmsra] JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.jts:main" from local module loader @353aa6fe (finder: local module finder @1da988ff (roots: /opt/pest3/jboss-eap-6.1.1/modules,/opt/pest3/jboss-eap-6.1.1/modules/system/layers/base)): javax.resource.spi.InvalidPropertyException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.jts:main" from local module loader @353aa6fe (finder: local module finder @1da988ff (roots: /opt/pest3/jboss-eap-6.1.1/modules,/opt/pest3/jboss-eap-6.1.1/modules/system/layers/base))
    at com.sun.genericra.util.ExceptionUtils.newInvalidPropertyException(ExceptionUtils.java:42)
    at com.sun.genericra.util.ObjectBuilderFactory$JndiObjectBuilder.createObject(ObjectBuilderFactory.java:100)
    at com.sun.genericra.util.ObjectBuilder.build(ObjectBuilder.java:99)
    at com.sun.genericra.inbound.AbstractConsumer.initializeAdministeredObjects(AbstractConsumer.java:95)
    at com.sun.genericra.inbound.AbstractConsumer.<init>(AbstractConsumer.java:63)
    at com.sun.genericra.inbound.async.EndpointConsumer.<init>(EndpointConsumer.java:57)
    at com.sun.genericra.inbound.EndpointConsumerFactory.createEndpointConsumer(EndpointConsumerFactory.java:45)
    at com.sun.genericra.inbound.EndpointConsumerFactory.createEndpointConsumer(EndpointConsumerFactory.java:58)
    at com.sun.genericra.GenericJMSRA.getXAResources(GenericJMSRA.java:279)
    at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryInflowImpl.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryInflowImpl.java:96)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jbossatx.jta.XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.java:51) [jbossjts-integration-4.17.7.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.7.Final-redhat-4]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:500) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.7.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.7.Final-redhat-4]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:158) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.7.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.7.Final-redhat-4]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:743) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.7.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.7.Final-redhat-4]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:371) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.7.Final-redhat-4.jar:4.17.7.Final-redhat-4]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.jts:main" from local module loader @353aa6fe (finder: local module finder @1da988ff (roots: /opt/pest3/jboss-eap-6.1.1/modules,/opt/pest3/jboss-eap-6.1.1/modules/system/layers/base))
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at com.sun.genericra.util.ObjectBuilderFactory$JndiObjectBuilder.createObject(ObjectBuilderFactory.java:95)
    ... 13 more
```

My stand alone xml looks like this

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/PestalozziFirebird" pool-name="PestalozziFirebird" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:firebirdsql:vmh-lcag-pest01-icapsit.lsy.fra.dlh.de/3050:BIS_PUBLISH_ICAP_LAP</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>jaybird-2.2.3.jar</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>3</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                        <flush-strategy>EntirePool</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>xxx</user-name>
                        <password>xxx</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT CAST(1 as INTEGER) FROM rdb$database</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <background-validation-millis>60000</background-validation-millis>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>20000</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="firebirdsql" module="org.firebirdsql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

Actually am trying to change the code from bean managed to container managed in that process i have used all XA transactions and connection strings.
But I am not very sure why this warning is coming.

Looks like i need to arrange XAResource recovery not sure how i can do.
Please help me.

Update..

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
            <resource-adapters>
                <resource-adapter id="genericra.rar">
                    <archive>
                        genericra.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="LogLevel">
                        info
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="ProviderIntegrationMode">
                        jndi
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="Password">
                        intPestalozzi456
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="UserName">
                        pestalozziInt
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="JndiProperties">
                        java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.tibco.tibjms.naming,java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory,java.naming.provider.url=tcp://vmh-lcag-eai04-test.lsy.fra.dlh.de:52706,java.naming.security.credentials=tstPestalozzi456,java.naming.security.principal=pestalozziTst
                    </config-property>
                </resource-adapter>
            </resource-adapters>
        </subsystem>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is only the datasource subsystem of the standalone.xml. Can you add some more informations? The error seems to be related with TIBCO, which settings do you have for it?

Comment: @Wallkan updated, But i feel those settings are correct because i am already receving messages from TIBCO.